# In BigQuery, what is the behaviour of WRITE_APPEND

Tags: google-bigquery

If I have a partitioned-by-date table with a WRITE_APPEND policy, what happens if I write data into existing partitions? Does it simply get ignored or it gets appended as the name indicates? My understanding is that it appends existing data in the same partition but not 100% sure.

The doc only says that "WRITE_APPEND: If the table already exists, BigQuery appends the data to the table.". This is highly ambiguous and doesn't even bother to speak about partitioned table.

Comment: WRITE_APPEND will always write the data. If the partition existis, the data will be appended, otherwise will create the partition first.

Comment: Thanks @DamiãoMartins. Can I say, if no partition is given, the doc means the whole table, but if partition is given, the doc means the partitioned part of the table?